# TomEE PolicyConfigurationFactory & TransactionManagerImpl error

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9, apache-tomee, tomee-8

I have a problem while trying to start my server TomEE PluME 8.0.1. Hereunder are my logs.

I’m doing a POC for a client, to know if we could pass one of their applications from weblogic to TomEE.
I deploy this application (EAR) in apps and I have the 2 errors beyond.

Can you tell me if you know how I could solve this problem?
I didn’t manage to find something helpful on the WEB.

I tried to configure a TransactionManager in system.properties but it changes nothing.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Here are my logs:

```
May 15, 2020 10:57:35 AM org.apache.openejb.util.OpenEJBErrorHandler handleUnknownError
SEVERE: FATAL ERROR: Unknown error in Assembler.  Please send the following stack trace and this message to users@tomee.apache.org :
 org.apache.xbean.recipe.ConstructionException: Error invoking factory method: public static org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.GeronimoTransactionManager org.apache.openejb.resource.GeronimoTransactionManagerFactory.create(java.lang.Integer,org.apache.openejb.util.Duration,boolean,byte[],java.lang.String,int,boolean,boolean,java.lang.Integer,org.apache.openejb.util.Duration,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,int,int,int,int) throws java.lang.Exception
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ReflectionUtil$StaticFactory.create(ReflectionUtil.java:1017)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ObjectRecipe.internalCreate(ObjectRecipe.java:279)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:96)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:61)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:49)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createTransactionManager(Assembler.java:3570)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.buildContainerSystem(Assembler.java:574)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.build(Assembler.java:494)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init>(OpenEJB.java:150)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatLoader.initialize(TomcatLoader.java:245)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.lifecycleEvent(ServerListener.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl
    at org.apache.openejb.resource.GeronimoTransactionManagerFactory.create(GeronimoTransactionManagerFactory.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.recipe.ReflectionUtil$StaticFactory.create(ReflectionUtil.java:1007)
    ... 22 more

...

SEVERE: Error destroying child
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:430)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:817)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1656)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1636)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:769)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2413)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1100)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:759)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1308)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1130)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)

May 15, 2020 10:57:36 AM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\Users\fnsanzabandi\tools\apache-tomee-plume-8.0.1\webapps\docs: PolicyConfigurationFactory class not found: Property javax.security.jacc.PolicyConfigurationFactory.provider not set
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1104)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:759)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1308)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1130)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: PolicyConfigurationFactory class not found: Property javax.security.jacc.PolicyConfigurationFactory.provider not set
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JaccPermissionsBuilder.install(JaccPermissionsBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.initEjbs(Assembler.java:1505)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:962)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Property javax.security.jacc.PolicyConfigurationFactory.provider not set
    at javax.security.jacc.PolicyConfigurationFactory$1.run(PolicyConfigurationFactory.java:86)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.jacc.PolicyConfigurationFactory.getPolicyConfigurationFactory(PolicyConfigurationFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JaccPermissionsBuilder.install(JaccPermissionsBuilder.java:59)
    ... 47 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I had added these jars because they were needed for my app:
 - jcl104-over-slf4j-1.4.1
 - slf4j-api-1.4.1

I had to change their versions to correct the problem. Changed version 1.4.1 to 1.7.21.